# Metasploit shell non-responsive

Tags: metasploit, powershell

Metasploit successfully executes the exploit, but after that, I get a non-responsive shell:
[image]

Do you know what could be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Try to troubleshoot the exploit keeping attention to some payload details, for example:

If you run `show options`:

1- default `TARGETURI` value is `/struts2-rest-showcase/orders/3`. Try to manually check if this uri exist in the target web application or properly change it.

2 - `exploit target` default value is `Unix (In-Memory)`. This suppose that you are attacking an unix system. Check if the target is windows or unix and change the value accordingly (`Powershell (In-Memory)` or `Windows (In-Memory)`). If you run `show targets` you can list the possible values:

```
   0   Unix (In-Memory)
   1   Windows (In-Memory)
   2   Python (In-Memory)
   3   PowerShell (In-Memory)
   4   Linux (Dropper)
   5   Windows (Dropper)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. The issue here is that, I don't know how to decide which is the right target uri. /struts2-rest-showcase/orders/3 exists on the page, however, the exploit doesn't seem to work. 
I have tried several payloads and targeturis, maybe you can give a hint, how to investigate the right uris in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Okay, somehow, magically it works now.